# ipmitool gets stopped when called in background

Tags: background-process, ipmitool

I am using ipmitool to get remote console output with SOL. This gets called from within a background process. When I call it in the foreground, it correctly logs the console output to the log file. But when called in the background, ipmitool doesn't work. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

ipmitool write the SOL data on the standout output(stdout) file descriptor. When called in background, ipmitool can't write to stdout because of which you are not seeing console logs.

If you want to run it as a background process, then redirect the stdout to a file and tail that file.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Still gets stopped, I'm thinking maybe because there's no stdin?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. Solution of redirecting stdout was not enough. 
This ended up working:

```
tail -f /dev/null --pid="$$" \
    | ipmitool -H "$ip" -U "$username" -P "$password" -I lanplus sol activate \
    2>> stderr.txt >> stdout.txt &
```

Idea of using `tail -f /dev/null` came form [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42901/how-to-do-nothing-forever-in-an-elegant-way). There are a few other solutions listed there, but I didn't try them.

`--pid="$$"` means this process will get killed when parent process gets killed, which is what I wanted, but may or may not fit your needs. You will probably need some mechanism for avoiding `tail -f` zombies.